# Can someone explain the asymptotic complexity of sorted and unsorted priority queues?

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap, complexity-theory, priority-queue

For a sorted underlying container, why does it take the priority queue O(nlogn) time to create, yet for an unsorted underlying container it only takes O(n) time to create?  Also, why does it take (in the sorted case) O(nlogn) to sort the priority queue?

In either case, are there any helpful diagrams that will help me understand the running times?  Is it faster to use a heap in these cases?

Comment: `Omega(nlogn)` is a proven lower bound for sorting (using comparisons based algorithms). Since you can sort using a "sorted Priority Queue", you cannot beat this bound.

Comment: @amit: I thik i could sort a SORTED list in O(1) as this seems to be the question: " why does it take (in the sorted case) O(nlogn) to sort the priority queue?"

Comment: @mikyra But the question does not ask about  sorted *input* it asks for a sorted *underlying container* - which means you need to sort any input you get, which is `Omega(nlogn)`

Comment: @amit: oops I thought there is an already sorted container as input - seems I must be reading better next time :)

Answer (score 0):

A priority queue could be implemented with a max-heap. And in fact, a max heap gives us the asymptotically optimal implementation for a priority queue. So, in the unsorted underlying container case, in order to create a priority queue we are only required to create a heap out of n elements, which can be done with the [Heapify algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) in O(n) time. In the sorted case, we are required to fully sort the elements which is known to be Theta(n) bound.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question can't be answered in general as there is no one and only way to implement a priority queue.

It's rather defined by the operations it is able to perform and there are many ways to implement it, a heap or an AVL tree just beeing some possibilities.

You will have to look up the implementation chosen by the STL implementation you are using to answer this question.

In the documentation of the SGI implementation it reads:

> [2] This restriction is the only reason for priority_queue to exist at
>   all. If iteration through elements is important, you can either use a
>   vector that is maintained in sorted order, or a set, or a vector that
>   is maintained as a heap using make_heap, push_heap, and pop_heap.
>   Priority_queue is, in fact, implemented as a random access container
>   that is maintained as a heap. The only reason to use the container
>   adaptor priority_queue, instead of performing the heap operations
>   manually, is to make it clear that you are never performing any
>   operations that might violate the heap invariant.

So it just seems to use a heap as you suggested.